# Relation that generates next prime

Tags: prolog, primes

I am trying to create a Prolog rule that relates a number to its next prime. I have it so that it can generate the next prime after a number, but it fails to find the numbers that a prime directly follows. For example, the following is as expected:

`next_prime(9, X)` gives `X = 11`.
`next_prime(200, X)` gives `X = 211`.

However, `next_prime(9, 13)` gives `true` is not expected, since 13 is not the next prime after 9, since 11 is.

Also, the rule doesn't work in reverse:
`next_prime(X, 13).` gives

```
Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
In:
   [2] 13 is _1410+1
   [1] next_prime(_1466,13) at line 22
```

I don't understand what this error message means.

Here is my code:

```
divisible_over(A, B) :-
    0 =:= A mod B,
    !.
divisible_over(A, B) :-
    A > B + 1,
    divisible_over(A, B + 1).

composite(A) :-
    divisible_over(A, 2).

prime(A) :-
    not(composite(A)).

next_prime(A, P) :-
    P is A + 1,
    prime(P),
    !.
next_prime(A, P) :-
    A0 is A + 1,
    next_prime(A0, P).
```

`prime` works fine. `next_prime` seems to be the only problematic rule.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Allow me to be the first person to suggest you try using [`clpfd`](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=clpfd-predicate-index) instead of the built-in arithmetic system.

Answer (score 1):

Argument not suff. inst. you get because of the line P is A+1. If you ask Prolog next_prie(X,13). this line evaluates to 13 is X+1. Prolog does not know what to do in this case because X has not a value yet -> this causes an error

I would do it like this:

```
% prolog just uses this if A and P are already numbers and checks then if there are no primes between the numbers
next_prime(A,P) :-
  number(A),
  number(P),!,
  no_prime_between(A,P).

next_prime(A, P) :-
    var(P), % this line checks if P is a variable
    P is A + 1,
    prime(P),!.

next_prime(A, P) :-
    var(P), % this line checks if P is a variable
    A0 is A + 1,
    next_prime(A0, P).

% this is used so your funciton works in both direction
next_prime(A, P) :-
    var(A), % this line checks if A is a variable
    A is P - 1,
    prime(A),!.

next_prime(A, P) :-
    var(A), % this line checks if A is a variable
    P0 is P - 1,
    next_prime(A, P0).

% a new methode I introduced, that checks if there is a prime between X, and X0.
no_prime_between(X,X0) :-
  X0 is X+1.
no_prime_between(X,_) :-
  X0 is X+1,
  prime(X0), !, false.
no_prime_between(X,Y) :-
  X0 is X+1,
  no_prime_between(X0,Y).
```

this results in the following output:

```html
?- next_prime(9,X).
X = 11 .

?- next_prime(X,11).
X = 7.

?- next_prime(9,11).
true .

?- next_prime(9,13).
false.
```

Comment: If you want to do a relational predicate in Prolog using integers, then use the CLP(FD) library instead of checking for `var(P)` etc. `use_module(library(clpfd)).` then you can do `P0 #= P - 1` in which case Prolog will solve for the variables.

Comment: @lurker Your solution is obviously a better one. But also I think it is a solution where someone new to prolog doesn't learn as much as coding it by hand. Thank for your productiv comment anyway.